# How to center a two column layout using Twitter Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap 3 for a website and have a main content area and a sidebar. At present both columns are aligned left side-by-side but I want them to be placed centrally on the page.

I have seen a number of solutions on SO where a single column is aligned using the CSS:

```
.col-centered {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This works but only for one of my columns. I tried nesting my two columns inside a column with size of twelve and tried to center that but to no avail.

I would prefer not to remove the float so that at small sizes the columns will stack but on all other sizes they would remain side-by-side.

Here is the basic structure of the HTML I am using:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-7 col-lg-6">
        </div>
        <aside class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-5 col-lg-6">
        </aside>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance,

nav

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/95883 using `.row` and having each column span half the grid or `6` should do it..

Comment: @Trevor thanks I think I understand what was going on I think I may need to override the padding-left and padding-right of the container to do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by overriding the padding-left and padding-right of the .container class in bootstrap 3.

```
.container {
    padding-right: 120px;
    padding-left: 120px;
}
```

It might be better to do the above with percentages so that it scales. I was thrown off by the fact that my sidebar was not extending fully to the end of the container and as a result though it was not being centered.

Adding the above override did it for me.

Many thanks to @trevor for his test bed.